# How to get one column value depend on another

Tags: mysql

I have data in my table like below. (There are many other columns in my table)

```
project_id | done_ratio  
1510 ------------ 100  
1510 ------------ 100  
1510 ------------ 100  
1511 ------------ 80  
1511 ------------ 90  
1511 ------------ 0  
1512 ------------ 0  
1512 ------------ 0
```

The query I want to write is get status depend on the done_ratio like following.
status for project_id 1510 is **done** because all done ratio is 100.
status for project_id 1511 is **working** because all done ratio is not 100 and 0.
status for project_id 1512 is **not_start** because all done ratio is 0.
Can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select project_id,
       case when avg(done_ratio) = 100 then 'done'
            when avg(done_ratio) > 0 then 'working'
            else 'not_start'
       end as status
from your_table
group by project_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to do is get status depend on all done_ratio of a specific project. As an example, a project with (100,90,20) done_ratio will show working not show done even if there is 100. 
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Then use `avg()` instead

Comment: Yes, I got it. avg() solved this problem. Thank you very much @juergen d.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) for that:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN done_ratio == 100 THEN 'done'
     WHEN done_ratio == 0 THEN 'not_start'
     ELSE 'working'
FROM tbl
```